# Stop Matlab resizing figure on axis change

Tags: matlab, scale

I'm plotting circles onto a grid. They are 5 (representing 5 meters).

```
pos = [0 0 5 5];
pos2 = [10 10 5 5];
rectangle('Position',pos,'Curvature',[1 1])
rectangle('Position',pos2,'Curvature',[1 1])
axis equal
axis([0 100 0 100])
```

The axis represents room size in this case 100x100 meters. Sometimes I want to compare for different room sizes such as 400x400

```
axis([0 400 0 400])
```

I need the circles in these positions but I need them to look the same size whatever the axis is set to. Currently as you increase the axis the circles get smaller and smaller I need them to stay the same size but the window/figure should get bigger.

Is this possible

Comment: Have you tried manipulating the parameters of your window/figure?

Comment: I didn't get it... You told, that circles must be fixed. So, if you are increasing your box size keeping circle's size fixed, your circle becomes smaller on your picture. This is correct. What do you want then?

Comment: @MikhailGenkin I need the circles in the positions in my first post but I need them to look the same size whatever the axis is set to. Currently as you increase the axis the circles get smaller and smaller I need them to stay the same size but the window/figure should get bigger.

Comment: This means, that size of your circles will be changed with new axes! So please, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your comments, you want this (feel free to change the value of a):

```
close all
a=100;
pos = [0 0 a/20 a/20];
pos2 = [a/10 a/10 a/20 a/20];
rectangle('Position',pos,'Curvature',[1 1])
rectangle('Position',pos2,'Curvature',[1 1])
axis equal
axis([0 a 0 a])
```

Explanation: for `a=100` code is the same. As you are changing `a`, which is the range of your axes, your circles are increasing in size proportionally (there radius will be `a/20`). Also the position of second circle should me modified appropriately.